# Converting float to string error with point

Tags: c#, floating-point

I'm working with a kinect sensor and Vector3 objects (C#).

The problem appears when I convert some of the Vector3 components to Strings in a log returning me numbers with 2 points. For example:

-5.4480440.014727

I tried 2 different options ("" + number; number.ToString("0.000000"); number.ToString("G")) but the result is the same so I don't know what else to think

Comment: Do you happen to know what the two dots actually represent? (how to convert that to real float value - how are they related)

Comment: "some of the Vector3 components to Strings in a log returning me numbers with 2 points" Can you show how you actually Convert those? There might be something wrong with the way you convert.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer in other ways.

Converting first the float to double, and then to String works.